# Basic jenkins pipeline bash error

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Jenkins pipeline versus Jenkins gui.

I have a basic jenkins job - it contain a bash step :

```
export CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable

git --version
node --version
npm -version
java -version

npm install

Xvfb :99 &
export DISPLAY=:99
npm run ci
```

it works fine with no errors.

I tried to covert it to a new jenkins pipeline -

```
node ('ubuntu-aws'){

env.JAVA_HOME="${tool '1.8.92'}"
env.PATH="${env.JAVA_HOME}/bin:${env.PATH}"
sh 'java -version'

timestamps {
    //sh "docker pull main-virtual.docker.vidible.aolcloud.net/main/travis-test"
    sh 'whoami'


        sshagent(['24195acf-44c2-4f07-98e4-13365b2e49dc']) {

            stage "git checkout"
            checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], gitTool: 'Default', submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'YYYYYYY', url: 'XXXXXXXX']]])

            sh '''git --version
                node --version
                npm --version'''

            withEnv(['CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable', 'CONTINUOUS_INTEGRATION=true']) {

                sh 'env'
                sh 'java -version'

                stage "npm install"
                sh "npm install"

                stage "npm run ci"

                sh '''Xvfb :99 &'''
                sh 'export DISPLAY=:99'

                sh "npm run ci"
                //sh 'npm run build'
                sh 'ls'
            }

        }//ssh agent

    archiveArtifacts allowEmptyArchive: true, artifacts: 'dist/*.*', excludes: null

}
```

}

and it failed

07:09:03 [31m03 01 2017 07:08:14.838:ERROR [launcher]: [39mCannot start Chrome
07:09:03
07:09:03 [31m03 01 2017 07:08:17.103:ERROR [launcher]: [39mCannot start Chrome
07:09:03
07:09:03 [31m03 01 2017 07:08:18.887:ERROR [launcher]: [39mCannot start Chrome

both jobs run on the same Jenkins server and on the same slave.

any idea for this error ?

Comment: I think that the export Display works only for the same sh step. not sure if it's the same for the Xvfb line. try to run it in one sh

Comment: yep , That did the magic , Thanks @Amityo !!